# jQuery load won't work without alert even with a callback function in place

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I load html content along with javascript (using `getScript`) on a page using the jquery load function with a callback. But I am encountering a strange situation in that the javascript that is being loaded isn't recognized either on the first try (it does work on the 2nd or subsequent try) or without an alert in place. I have read through similar situations and the suggested solution is to have a callback function for load. But I already have a callback function in place. Here is the code:

```js
$("[id^=ajax_]").click(function(e){
  var linkid = $(this).attr("id");
  var arr = linkid.split("_");
  var link = arr[1];
  ajax_load_content_and_get_script(link);
});

function ajax_load_content_and_get_script(link) {
    var url = "/" + link;
    $("#pagecontent").load(url + "/ajax", function() {
      //alert(); //works with this un-commented 
      $.getScript("/js/" + link + ".js");
    });
}
```

As you could see above, the script that is being loaded (with getScript) is recognized and works fine if I have the alert statement uncommented. But without the alert, the script isn't recognized. I am already using a callback function for the load as seen above.

Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: I copy/paste your code and it is working fine to me. What browser do you use? Additionally check status of the response from load( ... ) function, by modifying your callback function to: function(response, status, xhr) {...}. What status you have?

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't recognized"? Are you getting an error in the Javascript console?

Comment: try to populate the `#pagecontent` with html() after it loaded from a standard ajax request with the `async` parameter = false, then put the getScript on success callback.

Answer (score 0):

look like this?

```
$("button").click(function(e){
  var linkid = $(this).attr("id");
  var arr = linkid.split("_");
  var link = arr[1];
  ajax_load_content_and_get_script(link);
});

function ajax_load_content_and_get_script(link) {
    var url = "/" + link;
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/ajax",
        type: 'POST',
        async:false
    }).success(function(data){){
         $("#pagecontent").html(data);
         $.getScript("/js/" + link + ".js");
    });

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aswzen/w4068ygL/3/